# Change ownership of a YouTube account over to another Google account

Tags: youtube, google-account, account-management

On a client project at work I had to create a YouTube account for them. We're about to hand over ownership of it all, but the issue is that the YouTube account is linked to my Google Account.

I don't want to give them the keys to my Google Account, so is there a way I can transfer ownership of a YouTube account (or link to another Google Account), so they have their own separate login?

Or will I have to contact YouTube support for them to transfer the account?

Comment: Any luck? What did you end up doing?

Comment: Sadly Collin we just created another Youtube account. Youtube take ages to respond after repeated emails to them with no response, when they did reply it was a cookie-cutter humanless response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have created the YouTube account after May 2009, which I am guessing you have, then there is no way that you can unlink the YouTube account from your Google account.

AFAIK not even raising a support ticket with YouTube will enable you to unlink your accounts.

Taken from [this YouTube Help Article](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=173914)

> Only certain types of YouTube Accounts
>   can unlink from Google Accounts.
>   Unlinking from a Google Account is **not**
>   an option for YouTube Accounts created
>   after May 2009.

This information can be found under `Linking Options` > `Can I unlink my YouTube Account from the Google Account?`

Comment: Damnit. I might just have to contact them and explain the situation. It's for a major Government client here in Australia, so it's pretty important. Surely they'll sympathise. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Dwayne: I'd be interested to see if they can do anything for you. I'm not sure whether this restriction is because there is no process available to do it or because it isn't technically possible.

Comment: I'll let you know how I go Barry.

Comment: This is not true anymore as of today. If you can add a Google+ profile, then you can migrate a YouTube Channel to another Google Account. But you have to add a Google+ Page for given YouTube Account and then transfer ownership.

See my Answer here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52081/separate-my-youtube-channel-from-my-current-google-account/57817#57817