# Separate my YouTube Channel from my current Google Account

Tags: youtube, google-account

I created a YouTube account linked to my Gmail account.

Now, I wish to separate them. The YouTube account is for a small business, and I would like it to have its own email and for other people to be able to login.

Is that possible, or do I have to delete and start again?

Comment: Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible. Youtube has no such feature.

Comment: @user221287 These types of statements are better left as comments, especially in this case where it seems to be asking more about Google accounts in general than YouTube.

Comment: http://www.blogsynthesis.com/transfer-youtube-channel-to-another-google-account/

seems promissing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new (or another) Google Account with an active **Google+ Profile**. But do not setup a G+ business Page there yet! You will transfer it together with your YouTube Channel to this new Google Account later.

• Then log into your old YouTube Account and link your Channel to a new **Google+ business Page**.

• Next add a new manager for that Goggle+ Page: Choose your newly created Google+ Profile (from above) as a manager.

• You have to wait 14 days

• and then you can transfer ownership of your Channel to the new manager.

---

the following How-to Tutorials should be of additional help:

~ [Transfer YouTube Channel **ownership** to another Google account](http://www.peggyktc.com/2013/09/transfer-ownership-of-your-youtube.html)

~ [How to Transfer YouTube Channel to another Google Account in 4 steps](http://www.blogsynthesis.com/transfer-youtube-channel-to-another-google-account/)

Comment: ~ YouTube Help: [Google Accounts and YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/69961)

Comment: ~ Google Accounts Help: [Change your username](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870)

Answer (score 0):

Google provides the following documentation:

[Manage channels linked to Google+ pages](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3046356) and 
[Change your username](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870) .

It may or may not be possible depending on how the accounts are linked and what you are trying to achieve.

You say 'Youtube Account' which does not exist any more. It may be helpful if you checked exactly what you have set up at the moment and if you have Google Plus integrated.